# Can we learn things about coefficients of cyclotomic polynomials from Sylow Theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, sylow-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

I am required to prove the following (which I believe was originally a result of Migotti):

Let $p,q$ be distinct primes. Show that the $pq$th cyclotomic polynomial has coefficients all -1, 0 or 1. Show moreover that if n is a product of at most two distinct primes then the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial has coefficients -1,0 or 1.

I have got an expression for the $pq$ case of $\frac{\Phi_q(t^p)}{\Phi_q(t)}$ where $\Phi_q(t) = 1+t+t^2+...+t^{q-1}$. I could slog through dividing that out, but it won't be pretty. I'm wondering if there is some deeper connection with Sylow theory that I could use, as the conditions look somewhat reminiscient of conditions on group order. Is it possible to formulate this usefully as a Sylow Theory problem?

Comment: See Theorem 16 of Gary Brookfield (2016) The Coefficients of Cyclotomic Polynomials, Mathematics Magazine, 89:3, 179-188, DOI: 10.4169/math.mag.89.3.179

Answer (score 2):

This is a famous theorem by Migotti (1883):

> If $n \in \mathbb N$ has at most two odd prime divisors, then the coefficients of $\Phi_n(x)$ are in $\{−1,0,1\}$.

For a proof, see [The Coefficients of Cyclotomic Polynomials](https://doi.org/10.4169/math.mag.89.3.179) by Brookfield (2016).

The proof is elementary and does not depend on Sylow theory.